# Multiple gifs on screen/in film

Tags: automation, gif, video

I am filming a project, and in one of the scenes I need to have a lot of smiley-faces.

For example [this](http://www.sherv.net/cm/emoticons/birthday/birthday-party-blower.gif):

[image]

How can I repeat this multiple times on the screen?

Comment: You will have to edit your question to be a little clearer: what kind of "film" are we talking about? What software, what methods? And are you after a way of just displaying a large amounts of animated gifs in video?

Comment: Are you filming the screen? If so, just repeat the GIF multiple times in HTML and show that on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you're filming the screen just make up an html document with the image copied over and over again. `<img src="http://www.sherv.net/cm/emoticons/birthday/birthday-party-blower.gif" />` Copy and paste that like a bunch until you fill the entire screen with that gif.

If you need it a bunch of times over and over again in an actual video just make a bunch of tracks and scale the gif down and arrange as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set it as the background image using CSS like so:

```
body {background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcKQD.gif);
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8fFhp/)